# How to upgrade magento 1.4 1.1 to 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.4, magento-1.7

I have a magento site in `1.4.1.1`.

Now i want to uprgade the site to `magento 1.7.0.2`.

I already did the following steps:

```
1.system->magento connet->magento connect manager
2.Then i enter the extension key as "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest"
3.Then pressed "Check for Upgrades" button.
```

now my window is bleow:

[image]

Then what i do next?

So how can i do the upgarde using magento connect manager?

How can i upgarde the magento site ?

Anyone have the solution?

My magento site in localserver.

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Database structure has major changes from 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2 so you need to upgrade first to 1.4.2 then you can upgrade to 1.7.0.2 directly.

I like the command line so I usually upgrade the system by command line, this is my procedure:

Substitute file downloader/pearlib/php/Archive/Tar.php with the patched version (it has a bug): http://www.mediafire.com/?35no55xuoeek20a

Prepare for Magento upgrade

Lets imaging that you have Magento 1.4.1.1. web store and you need to upgrade it to 1.5. or 1.6 version. First of all it is highly recommended to backup your live store files and database.

Next you need to get SSH access from your hosting provider and connect to your server via SSH protocol. After connection via SSH go to your store folder and execute these commands:

1 – Change permissions on lib/pear folder to writable (recursively):

```
chmod -R 777 lib/PEAR
```

2 – Execute this command to prepare Magento for upgrade:

```
./pear mage-setup
```

Most likely you will see this result after command execution:

```
Channel “connect.magentocommerce.com/core” is already initialized
```

Upgrade from Magento 1.4.1.x to Magento 1.4.2.0

This step is necessary even if you upgrade your Magento store to 1.5 or 1.6 versions.

3 – Execute Magento upgrade command:

```
./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable
```

Output of the command will show you what core packages were upgraded:

```
…
upgrade ok: channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Mage_Centinel-1.4.2.0
upgrade ok: channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default-1.4.2.0
upgrade ok: channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Phoenix_Moneybookers-1.2.3
upgrade ok: channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Find_Feed-1.0.7
upgrade ok: channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Interface_Adminhtml_Default-1.4.2.0
```

4 – When this part of the upgrade will be complete, enter these commands:

```
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
```

You will see this result after command execution:

```
Successfully added: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
```

It means that Magento connect 2.0 channel was added to the channels list successfully.

5 – Next, enter this command:

```
./mage sync
```

The result will be:

```
…
Successfully added: community/Mage_Locale_en_US-1.4.2.0
Successfully added: community/Interface_Install_Default-1.4.2.0
Successfully added: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers-1.2.3
Successfully added: community/Mage_Downloader-1.5.0.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Google_Checkout-1.4.2.0
```

Upgrade to Magento 1.4.2.0 is complete and now you can proceed with upgrade to Magento 1.5.1.0 or 1.6.0.0 version.

empty var/cache & var/session folder
empty browser cache

visit your website to trigger the update

Update time 15min

---

---

---

Upgrade from Magento 1.4.2.0 to Magento 1.5.10 or Magento 1.6.0.0

Now you can upgrade your store to version 1.5 or 1.6.

Before proceeding with this part of Magento upgrade, it is very important to see to what version Magento upgrade scripts will upgrade your store. Enter this command to check this:

```
./mage list-upgrades
```

If you will see this result:

```
Updates for community:
Mage_All_Latest: 1.4.2.1 => 1.6.0.0
Lib_Js_Mage: 1.4.2.0 => 1.6.0.0
Lib_Varien: 1.4.2.0 => 1.6.0.0
Lib_Phpseclib: 1.4.2.0 => 1.5.0.0
```

It means that your Magento will be upgraded to version 1.6.0.0. If it is not what you need you can change upgrade channel to “stable” and upgrade your Magento to version 1.5.1.0.

6 – Enter this command to change the upgrade channel to stable:

```
./mage config-set preferred_state stable 
   or
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

After this the "./mage list-upgrades" command will show you this result:

```
Updates for community:
Mage_All_Latest: 1.4.2.1 => 1.5.1.0.1
Lib_Js_Mage: 1.4.2.0 => 1.5.1.0
Lib_Varien: 1.4.2.0 => 1.5.1.0
Lib_Phpseclib: 1.4.2.0 => 1.5.0.0
Mage_Core_Adminhtml: 1.4.2.0 => 1.5.1.0
Mage_Core_Modules: 1.4.2.0 => 1.5.1.0
```

7 – After channel selection you can upgrade your Magento to 1.5.1.0 (or to Magento 1.6.0.0) using this command:

```
./mage upgrade-all –-force
```

You will see upgraded packages on your screen:

```
…
Package upgraded: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.6.0.0
Package upgraded: community/Lib_Mage 1.6.0.0
Package upgraded: community/Lib_ZF 1.11.1.0
Package upgraded: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.1
Package upgraded: community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.11.1.0
```

Now the upgrade is complete and you can execute database upgrade visiting your Magento store in your browser. If everything was upgraded correctly, you will see upgraded store in your browser.

You can check version of your store in the footer of Magento administration panel.

empty var/cache & var/session folder
empty browser cache

visit your website to trigger the update

Update time 60min depend on your hardware

This works for many of my customers.

I hope this can help you

I'm a Freelancer if you need help.

Comment: I've used this a few times now to go from 1.4.1.1 to 1.7.0.2 and it works really well. Thanks!

Comment: Just followed these directions to upgrade a 1.4.0.1 install to 1.7.0.2.  Worked well aside from some environment-specific issues.

Comment: When you are calling your browser to upgrade, make sure you have the execution time set to at least an hour. Alternatively you can call the index.php from the shell which hasn't got a timelimit by defaullt

Comment: i am stucked at ./mage upgrade-all –-force
could you help me out with this additonally error in frontend

Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pedicure/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529

Comment: I ran into server timeout issues when performing this upgrade. To fix it, I had to temporarily set the `max_execution_time = 600` in my php.ini file and restarted the web server.

Comment: What do you do if ./mage list-upgrades returns nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Magento using the MagentoConnect Manager

```
Go to http://<YOUR_SERVER>/downloader
Log in using a user who has full permissions
Make sure to select “Clear all sessions after successful install or upgrade”
```

This will help you out.

Comment: i did the above steps,i checked the check box and pressed the check for upgrade button.i got the second image in my question

Comment: What issue are you facing now?

Comment: i need to upgrade the magento site version from 1.4.1.1 to 1.7.0.2.thats my issue.

Comment: If you are not able to directly upgrade your site from 1.4 to 1.7. then try updating your site to first 1.5 version. It would be a bit easy job for you later

Comment: k,then how can i upgrade it to 1.5?

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento#upgrading_magento_using_the_magentoconnect_manager). Maybe you need the step "How to upgrade from tarball installation" afterwards.

Comment: nothing can i understandable.becuase i am new in magento.ssh is strange for me

Comment: Seems that package Mage_All_Latest-stable is not available anymore via PEAR? Trying to upgrade from 1.4.1.0 to 1.9.1.0 using instructions here:
http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/
ssh command ./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable results in error:  "channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Mage_All_Latest-stable" is not valid . I looked in  http://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Chiara_PEAR_Server_REST/c/ and /c/Default/ and downloaded the package, packagesinfo and categories.xml manually, and the package "Mage_All_Latest-stable" does not seem to exist in there.