# Magento update from 1.4.2 to 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.7

I have problem with update magento 1.4.2 to 1.7. When I try to use `./pear list-upgrades`, I get the message of not having any upgrades at the moment.

Am I missing anything ?

And when reading tutorial on the net, they use `./mage` which is a replacement for `./pear`, where can I get it and can I use it for the current version of Magento ?

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install the 1.7.0.2 files on top of the existing install (in a test environment of course). Clear the cache and voila, upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that Upagrade Magento without problem then It not Possible, I am do this and its work for me

But you can do this for Upgrade Magento 1.4 to 1.7

1) Backup your current Site Files and Database, and Do this on local because when you Upgrade do not reload page before complete all steps

2) Download Newer Version From http://www.magentocommerce.com/download here,

then Extract that zip file in Directory

3) Upload newer Version Files on your Current Site

4) Delete your site cache, Index Management

5)  Reload your Current Site, your database upgrade automatically don't anything with Database

now you can see the database vesion at bottom ver 1.7 [what ever you upgrade]

Enjoy!!!