# Magento Upgrade Using Pear

Tags: magento

I would like to upgrade my magento site using:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

I am wondering if there is a way to run the same command but instead of using Mage_All_Latest can I choose the version I want to upgrade to?

I would like to upgrade to Community 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 1.4.x or less?  If so, then see the following SO question & answer.  It contains a great guide for upgrading Magento from 1.3 or 1.4: [How to upgrade magento 1.4 1.1 to 1.7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2)

Once you get past 1.3.x then you could just copy the 1.6 structure to your site and flush your cache.  The next page load will upgrade you to the version that you copied over.

Always back up your files AND database before attempting any upgrade procedure.