# What is the Upgrade Process for Magento from v1.4 1.1 to v1.7.0.2?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento site in v1.4.1.1. I want to upgrade my magento site to magento v1.7.0.2.

I am unable to upgrade the site using magento connect manager because magento connect manager is not displaying any available updates?

How can I upgrade the site using magento connect manager?

If anyone have the solution, please reply me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2

Comment: I like the Magento Connect Manager for upgrade. This is not the procedure to upgrade the magento by magento connect manager.

Comment: Upgrade first to 1.4.2.0, there are a lot of changes between 1.4.1.1 and 1.4.2.0. And you will have a lot less database conversion errors and fail on the next step for the misperceived extra work.