# Magento Connect Manager 1.4.1.1. not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I am trying to upgrade Magento 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2 (and then to 1.7), but cannot get to 1.4.2.

I am trying to follow the steps here - [How to upgrade magento 1.4 1.1 to 1.7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2) by using the Magento Connect Manager.

However, the downloader directory was deleted sometime in the past on my installation, and so I have copied the downloader directory from a new Magento 1.4.1.1 installation.

The problem is every-time I go to /downloader and I try to log in it redirects to downloader/index.php?A=index&loggedin and it never gives me the screen you are meant to get that will give you the possibility to "Install New Extensions", "Manage Existing Extensions" and "Settings".

Note that "it seems" to log in because if I enter a wrong username and password combination it will throw an error saying Invalid user name or password.

I tried the following with no result:

- using the .htaccess of a new Magento 1.4.1.1 installation
- clearing var/cache and var/session
- clearing all the cookies
- logging in with Private Browsing browser feature

Thanks

Comment: I would be very interested to see some opinions on this - I'm on 1.4.2 and have the exact same issue. I.e. Connect Manager doesn't seem to do anything at all.