# Magento packages upgrading to same version

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

When upgrading magento via ssh, it upgrades to the same version... Here is an example:

```
./mage list-upgrades
```

returns 'Mage_All_Latest: 1.8.1.0 => 1.9.1.1'
 then I do:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

which returns 'Package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.8.1.0 installed successfully'

TL;DR: Magento packages upgrade to the version they are already on, instead of upgrading to the newest version available.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to upgrade list of modules by ./mage upgrade-all.
You might have to replace mage with pear though.

When the process is complete you’ll see a list of modules saying 'already installed', 'package upgraded' etc...

Some of links which will help you.

- http://www.mageplace.com/news-blog/how-to-upgrade-your-magento-to-1-8-0-0-version.html
- [How to upgrade magento 1.4 1.1 to 1.7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2)